# Swagger: where to provide sample json for a call?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

I'm new to swagger and I'm trying to start documenting an API. I'd like to include examples of requests/responses in my documentation, not just the schema definition itself.

There is an "examples" feature on the responses object, however, when I fill this out, it does not show up anywhere in the generated documentation. Is this just a missing feature from swagger for the time being, or am I using this feature incorrectly?

Here is my spec (I am aware I haven't implemented security properly yet):

```
swagger: '2.0'
schemes: ['https']
info:
  version: 1.0.0.0
  title: 'Test API'
  contact:
    name: Support
    url: 'www.nowhere.com'
    email: 'test@example.com'
consumes: ['application/json']
produces: ['application/json']
paths:
  /Variables:
    get:
      summary: 
        Returns the list of all variables in the system.
      description:
        Returns the list of all variables in the system.
      tags: ['Variables']
      consumes: ['application/json']
      produces: ['application/json']
      parameters:
        - name: "Authorization"
          in: header
          description: "Provide the OAuth access token in the format of: Bearer token_value"
          type: string
      responses:
        '200':
          description: Successful response
          schema:
            $ref: '#/definitions/Variables'
          examples:
            application/json:
              VariableToken: Name
              VariableGroupName: Main
              DataType: text
              VariableDisplayName: Name
definitions:
  Variables:
    type: array
    items:
      title: Variable
      type: object
      properties:
        VariableToken:
          type: string
          format: string
        VariableGroupName:
          type: string
          format: string
        DataType:
          type: string
          format: string
        VariableDisplayName:
          type: string
          format: string
```

Comment: I think in your examples section, you simply reference the object definition. Also, do yourself a favor an switch to the JSON style of swagger declaration. It makes life much easier once your definition file gets huge.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I am hand editing for an API that doesn't exist yet, so I'm writing in YAML, but the swagger editor will let me download and convert to json if I'd like, so I can represent in either format.

Comment: Yeah, the editor works pretty well until your files I've grows, then it can get very sluggish. I opted for hand editing in Notepad since it was really easy to redeploy and check the changes. Just a tip I learned!

Comment: Thanks. Good to know. Do you have any idea where the editor stores the file you're working on? I can't seem to find it anywhere in the dist folder. I know I can export it and save it locally, but I'd like to know where the WIP file lives.

Comment: Also, just a heads up, the editor has options in Preferences->Preferences to disable live rendering and auto-complete which is intended to speed up the typing experience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out. I was putting my examples in the right place, however, Swagger Editor does not display this in the preview window. Swagger UI, however, will generate the UI with this information given.